# Line chart of improvement where children begin at different ages

Tags: linechart

I am trying to create an overlaid Line Chart which shows children's improvement over time but where some children start at age 6, others 8, 9 etc. This is the code that I used but it produces an odd result. I don't know if I need to structure my data file better or what:

## The first lines of my data looks like this:

```
Name    Participant Age Correct
Becky   1           9   22
Becky   2           12  28
Byron   3           8   25
Byron   4           13  21

dat = read.table("Data03_IMPROVE1.txt", T)
head(dat)
attach(dat)
```

## Convert factor to numeric for convenience

```
dat$Participant <- as.numeric(dat$Participant) 
ntrees <- max(dat$Participant)
```

## Get the range for the x and y axis

```
xrange <- range(Age) 
yrange <- range(Correct)
```

## Set up the plot

```
plot(xrange, yrange, type="n", xlab="Age",
     ylab="Correct" ) 
colors <- rainbow(ntrees) 
linetype <- c(1:ntrees) 
plotchar <- seq(18,18+ntrees,1)
```

## Add lines

```
for (i in 1:ntrees) { 
  tree <- subset(dat, Participant==i) 
  lines(dat$Age, dat$Correct, type="b", lwd=1.5,
        lty=linetype[i], col=colors[i], pch=plotchar[i]) 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code produces a chart (which stack overflow didn't let me post) that has a one to many relationship between the lines when it should just produce parallelish lines with two age points